# Eclipse mars is not showing Expressions view

Tags: windows-7-x64, eclipse-mars

I clicked on **Windows->Show View->Expressions** in eclipse mars. But it is not showing *Expressions* view.

Comment: I have no problem at all with the expression view in Mars, you should take a look at your configuration and your log files ...

Comment: Where should I look for configuration?

Comment: I can't say without knowing more details, do you have some errors in the log file ? What plugin you have installed ? Have you tried to reinstall Eclipse from scratch ?

Comment: In my other workspace it is showing the view.

Comment: So, it something related to the workspace configuration.

Comment: Now I checked the workspace which is not showing **Expressions** view, is also not showing **Breakpoints** and **Variables** view.

Comment: Please file a bug to Eclipse bugzilla system, posting your Eclipse workspace configuration files ...

Comment: Where can I find configuration file?

Comment: There is a .metadata invisible folder inside the workspace ...

Answer (score 0):

I closed the eclipse then deleted the folder .metadata and .recommenders from workspace. Then I opened eclipse, now It is showing the views.